# Autocompletetextview items not expanding

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Autocompletetextview items not expanding due to the size of items in android. i did set dropdown height. but still the same. i am searching places from Google using the autocomplete. please help me someone.

Comment: Please show some code and xml file too.

Comment: Add more information about what you are already done.

Comment: <com.example.xxxxx.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/this_Location_search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkout"
                android:background="#4978A9"
                android:hint="@string/hintword"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    
                android:textSize="14sp" />

Comment: i am getting the result of items but basically should show 5 items but currently shows only 1 or 2. when i press backspace only showing all 5 items in the autcomplete list